# Searching for unique value and call sub, if not go to next cell

Tags: excel, vba, loops, unique

I am trying to create automatic call for a sub based on unique values.

Column E
[The order is in column E](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvjsD.png)

```
Sub FindDate()

Dim Cell As Range


'For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A50")
'    If Cell.Value = [Today()] Then
'    Cell.Select
'ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Select
'    End If
'Exit For
'Next



For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.Range("E2:E100")

If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then


End If
Exit For
Next

For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.Range("E2:E100")
If ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0) Then

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

        
           Call EmailOrder
    
           ' ElseIf ActiveCell.Value <> ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0) Then Call EmailOrder
            'ElseIf ActiveCell.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
            End If
        
Next Cell


End Sub
```

At the moment with this code (I know it is a really messy but I am just a VBA beginner) when I select the second PAU21001316 (from the picture) then it is calling my EmailOrder sub for PAU21001316 and PAU21001318 but not for the PAU21001319 and PAU21001320.

The code should do : If I select a cell, let's say PAU21001309 to look if the cell above ( or below) is the same value, if it's the same to move one cell below if not to run **Call EmailOrder** and after to move to the next cell and to do the same. Then If a cell is empty to stop.

The point is to run every unique value at the same time.

The other thing that I was trying to do (the first code as comment) was to go to the today's date and move 4 columns which will go to the first Order number. It's moving the active cell but after that do nothing, just looping.

If anyone can help me to finish my code I will be grateful.

```
Sub EmailOrder(c As Range)


    Dim ActiveC As Variant
    Dim DirFile As String
    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strbody As String
    Dim SigString As String
    Dim Signature As String
    Dim xOutMsg As String
    Dim Timenow As String
    
    Dim signImageFolderName As String
    Dim completeFolderPath As String
    
   Dim colFiles As New Collection

'GetFiles "C:\xxx\", ActiveC & ".pdf", True, colFiles
'If colFiles.Count > 0 Then
'    'work with found files
'End If

    
    If Time < TimeValue("12:00:00") Then
Timenow = "Good Morning"
ElseIf Time > TimeValue("12:00:00") And Time < TimeValue("17:00:00") Then
Timenow = "Good Afternoon"
Else
Timenow = "Good Evening"
End If
   
    xOutMsg = Timenow & ", <br> <br> xxx<br/>"


ActiveC = Application.ActiveCell.Value

Dim sRes As String
Dim po As Range
Dim rg As Range
Dim b2 As Range

Set po = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)

    
    Set rg = Sheets("Email").Range("B1:D200")
    Set b2 = po
    
    sRes = Application.VLookup(b2, rg, 3, True)


'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False



DirFile = "C:\xxx\" & ActiveC & ".pdf"
     If Dir(DirFile) = "" Then
  MsgBox "File does not exist", vbCritical
    
  End If
  
  
  Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)


    'Change only Mysig.htm to the name of your signature
    SigString = Environ("appdata") & _
                "\Microsoft\Signatures\xxx.htm"
                
                signImageFolderName = "xxxfiles"
                completeFolderPath = Environ("appdata") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\" & signImageFolderName


    If Dir(SigString) <> "" Then
        Signature = GetBoiler(SigString)
        
        Signature = VBA.Replace(Signature, signImageFolderName, completeFolderPath)
    Else
        Signature = ""
    End If

'Create Outlook email with attachment
  On Error Resume Next
  
    With OutMail
    
     .To = sRes
     .CC = ""
     .BCC = ""
     .Subject = "xxx " & ActiveC
     .HTMLBody = xOutMsg & "<br>" & Signature
     .Attachments.Add "C:xxx\" & ActiveC & ".pdf"
     .Display
     
    End With
    
    Call FindDate
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
   
End Sub

Function GetBoiler(ByVal sFile As String) As String
'Dick Kusleika
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = FSO.GetFile(sFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    GetBoiler = ts.readall
    ts.Close
End Function
```

This is the main code, made form different codes. The main purpose is to get the value of the active cell and look in to the folder (I couldn't do to look in to the sub folders) for the file name.pdf and the to attach it to the email. The other part is to look for the supplier name in column H and VLOOKUP to another sheet "Email" for the supplier email and add it to the "To" section. The other code is for the signature and the body of the email.

The code is working but only when I select the specific cell. But it will be faster if is doing every PO for the day automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim f As Range, c As Range
    
    Set f = Range("A1:A50").Find(Date)  'Look for today's date
    If f Is Nothing Then Exit Sub       'Today not found....
    
    Set c = f.Offset(0, 4) 'move over to Col E
    Do While Len(c.Value) > 0
        If c.Offset(1, 0).Value <> c.Value Then
            EmailOrder c       'pass cell directly to your called sub
        End If
        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0) 'move down one row
    Loop
End Sub

Sub EmailOrder(c As Range)
    Const FLDR As String = "C:\xxx\" 'start search here

    Dim ActiveC As Variant
    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strbody As String
    Dim SigString As String
    Dim Signature As String
    Dim sRes As String
    Dim po
    Dim rg As Range, b2 As Range
    Dim signImageFolderName As String, completeFolderPath As String
    
    Dim colFiles As Collection

    ActiveC = c.Value
    po = c.Offset(0, 3).Value
    Set rg = Sheets("Email").Range("B1:D200")
    
    sRes = Application.VLookup(po, rg, 3, True) 'False?
    
    Set colFiles = GetMatches(FLDR, ActiveC & ".pdf") 'find any matches
    If colFiles.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "File '" & ActiveC & ".pdf' does not exist", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'what to do if >1 files found?
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    'Change only Mysig.htm to the name of your signature
    SigString = Environ("appdata") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\xxx.htm"
    signImageFolderName = "xxxfiles"
    completeFolderPath = Environ("appdata") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\" & signImageFolderName
    If Dir(SigString) <> "" Then
        Signature = VBA.Replace(GetBoiler(SigString), signImageFolderName, completeFolderPath)
    End If

    With OutMail
        .To = sRes
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "xxx " & ActiveC
        .HTMLBody = TimeGreeting & ", <br> <br> xxx<br/>" & Signature
        .Attachments.Add colFiles(1).Path 'assuming you only want the first match if >1
        .Display
    End With
    
    Call FindDate
    
End Sub

Function TimeGreeting() As String
    If Time < TimeValue("12:00:00") Then
        TimeGreeting = "Good Morning"
    ElseIf Time > TimeValue("12:00:00") And Time < TimeValue("17:00:00") Then
        TimeGreeting = "Good Afternoon"
    Else
        TimeGreeting = "Good Evening"
    End If
End Function
```

Function for file searching:

```vb
'Return a collection of file objects given a starting folder and a file pattern
'  e.g. "*.txt"
'Pass False for last parameter if don't want to check subfolders
Function GetMatches(startFolder As String, filePattern As String, _
                    Optional subFolders As Boolean = True) As Collection

    Dim fso, fldr, f, subFldr
    Dim colFiles As New Collection
    Dim colSub As New Collection
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    colSub.Add startFolder '<< start with the top-level folder
    
    Do While colSub.Count > 0
        Set fldr = fso.getfolder(colSub(1))
        colSub.Remove 1  '<< remove from queue
        For Each f In fldr.Files 'check all files
            If UCase(f.Name) Like UCase(filePattern) Then colFiles.Add f
        Next f
        If subFolders Then 'add subfolders to queue for listing
            For Each subFldr In fldr.subFolders
                colSub.Add subFldr.Path
            Next subFldr
        End If
    Loop
    Set GetMatches = colFiles
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. Now it start to looping only one file and opening multiple emails with the same number. I did that before with the loop and went to look for another solution. I am not sure if it's from my other code as it is very messy but it is working for a single value.

Comment: I added the code for the emails as maybe there will be the problem with the loop. I am getting an error if I am on a random cell and the code stops and marks " sRes = Application.VLookup(b2, rg, 3, True)" If I am on the PO and the file exist in the folder it starts to create the same email with the same file over and over. (not going to the next).

Comment: In `EmailOrder` instead of `ActiveCell` use `c`   The code does not select/activate anything, but passes the cell to work with directly to `EmailOrder`.  That's the most robust way to structure your code.

Comment: Thank you. You are really the best. :) Everything is working now. I am going to structure my code now better as I know it is a real mess and disgrace for coders :)

Comment: Sorry for the extra question but do you know an easy way to look in a sub folders? I tried several codes but they were too long and complicated and I would mess something definitely if I try to implement them. Well I will try at some point as I love to find a solutions to problems but if there's a easy way I would be grateful.

I need somehow `DirFile = "C:\xxx\" & c & ".pdf"` this to look in the subfolders and the attachment. If not, then I will try the hard way and maybe will learn something new :)

Comment: See additions above

Comment: Thank you again for the help. As I am still a beginner I think I undestood the code but when I try to add "col" to attachments it shows me an error. I am adding it here  ```.Attachments.Add``` col and here (for message if can't find the file) :
 ```DirFile = col
     If Dir(DirFile) = "" Then
  MsgBox "File does not exist", vbCritical``` then it shows me "Argument not optional"

Comment: See edits above to `EmailOrder` - should be almost there.

Comment: Thank you, now it's working perfectly! I only removed ``` Call FindDate``` from Order as it makes a loop and it was creating same email and file over and over. Thank you again for the help, hopefully now I will reduce the time for my orders :) … and of course will go to the next VBA project so I could learn more and more how to create macros like you some day.